# Laravel Cache retrieving issue

Tags: laravel

I am storing value in `Cache` but when i try to get value from `cache` it returns null

```
function storeIds(Request $request){
    $items="120,130,140,150";
    Cache::put('Ids', $items, 55);
    return response()->json(['success' => true], 200);
} 

function getIds(){
  $ids = Cache::get('Ids');
  var_dump($ids); //null
}
```

I'm storing cache value to one function and try to access another function but not able to get `null` value

I have set `CACHE_DRIVER=array` .env file of laravel project

Can I change Cache driver runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can set and get Cache driver runtime.

**SET**

```
Cache::store('file')->put('Ids', $items, 55);
```

**GET**

```
Cache::store('file')->get('Ids');
```

Answer (score 1):

You used array cache driver, it doesn't persist data and it stores the item in php array just for testing. for array driver, you can put and get cache key in the same request. 
recommendation for using cache driver:

**Development**

- File
- Database

**Production**

- Redis
- Memcached